# Include page javascripts conflicting with outer page javascripts

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

My problem is a little difficult to explain, but I will try.
I have 2 jsp pages Outer.jsp and Inner.jsp

**Outer.jsp**

Script: src="tabs.js"

var PageTabs = "Tab1"

@include "Inner.jsp"

**Inner.jsp**

Script: src="tabs.js"

var PageTabs = "Tab2~Tab3~Tab4"

Both the jsp pages use the same tabs.js to render some tab elements on the page. The "PageTabs" variable is one of the many common variables that are used by tabs.js. So what happpens is while rendering, the tabs.js takes the latest "PageTabs" variable i'e var PageTabs = "Tab2~Tab3~Tab4" even while rendeing tabs of Outer.jsp.

Note: The page variables and tabs.js are part of standard elements recieved from client. So they have to be used to give the same look and feel for application. 
What I need is a way to isolate the "Inner.jsp" from accessing scripts of "Outer.jsp". This will prevent the tabs element from being confused over which variables to use.

I hope I am somewhat clear. Please let me know if I need to provide any more clarifications. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is interpreted top-to-bottom inside a page, so your second `PageTabs` value overrides the first one. One option is to use a different name for the variable (and parameterize tabs.js functions rather than rely on global vars.)

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Unfortunately there are a lot of shared elements on screen. I know it is a bad design, but I will have to live with that. Is there a was for inner page to be isolated from outer ? Or else I will have to rewrite the tabs.js completely

Comment: As I said, there is no "inner page" our "outer page" context for JavaScript as long as it is operating within the same page. One option you can implement is turn inner page into an `<iframe>` (if possible.) But if inner.jsp and outer.jsp render different (non-separable) parts of the same page, you are out of luck.

Comment: Thanks, I will try your IFrame approach.

Answer (score 0):

When using jsp include, one of a very useful skill is to make your .js code modular . This is also an important method to encapsulate code and avoid conflict.

tab.js:

```
var tabModule = (function(my){
   var model;
   return {
      setModel: function(model){/*....*/}
      //other api functions
   }
})(tabModoule||{});
```

Outer.jsp:

```
tabModule.setModel({PageTabs : "Tab1"});
```

Innder.jsp:

```
 tabModule.setModel({PageTabs : "Tab2~Tab3~Tab4"});
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, will try your approach.